why is total moles (initial) = total moles at equilibrium, when △ng=0?
Why is it always true that for a reaction when △ng=0, the total number of moles of gases taken initially is equal to the total number of moles when equilibrium is reached?

Please edit the question to define the symbols you are using

Why is it always true that if I never spent nor earned any money during the day, in the evening I will have in my pocket the same amount that I had in the morning?

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

When (\Delta ng=0), the total number of moles of gases taken initially is equal to the total number of moles when equilibrium is reached because the forward and reverse reactions are proceeding at the same rate.
In a chemical reaction, equilibrium is reached when the forward and reverse reactions occur at the same rate. This means that the concentrations of the reactants and products do not change over time, and there is no observable change in the system's properties. This state is called dynamic equilibrium. Effect of volume changes
When there are equal numbers of moles on both sides of a reaction, changes in volume do not affect the equilibrium. However, if the volume changes, the equilibrium will shift in the direction that produces more or fewer moles of gas.
